# Label Git repository in AppVeyor build using environment variable

Tags: git, environment-variables, yaml, appveyor

I am trying to label a repository after a successful build in AppVeyor. I have read the following resources:

- [Environment variables](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables)
- [appveyor.yml reference](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/appveyor-yml)
- [Pushing to remote Git repository from a build](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/git-push)

But I don't know how to substitute in an AppVeyor environment variable. Here is the Yaml that I am using:

```cmd
on_success:
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  - ps: Add-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:access_token):x-oauth-basic@github.com`n"
  - git tag -a release/$($env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)
  - git push origin release/$($env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)
```

This results in the following error in the AppVeyor build log

```
git config --global credential.helper store
Add-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:access_token):x-oauth-basic@github.com`n"
git tag -a release/$($env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)
fatal: 'release/$($env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)' is not a valid tag name.
Command exited with code 128
```

Given that the powershell Add-Content line is supposed to work as per the example how are you supposed to substitute variables into the git commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be:

```
- git tag -a release/%APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%
- git push origin release/%APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%
```